# Cannot find symbol on clean generate release

Tags: gradle, gson, proguard, retrofit2, android-proguard

Im creating an external module or should i say a library for an existing mobile project app as I wont be able to tweak its internals(codes,configuration etc),

The sole purpose of this library is just to perform API calls (i.e accept and return data between the server and the client project(app) ), it works perfectly fine on the development, but when im trying to build the library this way

```
gradlew clean build generateRelease --stacktrace
```

Im having these kinds of errors on stacktrace

```
 error: cannot find symbol
 @SerializedName("FirstName")
 ^
```

I found out that retrofit does have

```
  minifyEnabled true
```

then I learned things about proguard rules
, using these lines from different sources and different tests,

```
 -keep class com.google.code.gson.** { *; }
 -keep class com.google.code.gson.annotations** { *; }
 -keep class retrofit2.** { *; }

 -keepclassmembernames interface * {
     @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
 }

 -keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
 -keepclassmembernames interface * {
     @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
 }

 -keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
 -keep class com.google.code.gson.stream.** { *; }

 -keepattributes Signature
 -keepattributes *Annotation*
```

different combinations of these rules, but I'm still having problems with building, these are coded on Library/Module's **proguard-rules.pro**

I dont know if the issues comes from proguard rules as I've tested alot of -keep attributes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

this is the build.gradle for the library

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.library'



android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

         testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
}

apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blundell/release-android-
library/master/android-release-aar.gradle'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, your project has built successfully with minification enabled after adding the following to your proguard file :

```
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
```

Comment: yes it did, i tried to upload it in bintary and used it as binary and it worked perfectly, thanks for answering and the code i need for the proguard, it really removed my doubt.